# iOS 13 wifi ssid in airplane mode

Tags: swift, core-location, xcode10, ios13

I'm currently updating my application in regards to what is being returned from CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo. I understand the privacy changes Apple implemented in regards to this starting on iOS 13 so i'm currently updating the implementation.

This is pretty straight forward. However the issue i'm running into is within this part of the app, the user will probably be in airplane mode (in-flight app). Regardless of the CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus(), even if it is .notDetermined which then triggers the requestWhenInUseAuthorization() method and once the user chooses either "Allow Once" or "Allow while Using App", i'm still not able to get the Wi-Fi ssid.

```
static func fetchSSIDInfo() -> String? {
    if isSimulator() {
        return "wireless"
    } else {
        if let interfaces: CFArray = CNCopySupportedInterfaces() {
            for i in 0..<CFArrayGetCount(interfaces) {
                let interfaceName: UnsafeRawPointer = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(interfaces, i)
                let rec = unsafeBitCast(interfaceName, to: AnyObject.self)
                // skips this in airplane mode
                if let unsafeInterfaceData = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo("\(rec)" as CFString) {
                    if let interfaceData = unsafeInterfaceData as Dictionary? {
                        let ssid = interfaceData["SSID" as NSObject] as? String
                        let bssid = interfaceData["BSSID" as NSObject] as? String

                        if ssid != "Wi-Fi" && bssid != "00:00:00:00:00:00" {
                            return ssid
                        } else {
                            return "invalid"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

In the code above, when in airplane mode it actually skips the if let unsafeInterfaceData. When it isn't in airplane mode, it's working as expected and returns either the ssid or the invalid string depending if user allows location services.

My question is how am I able to get this working on airplane mode? Maybe i'm missing something, but at this point not too sure.

Comment: So, I just did a test in iOS13 (after removing an earlier comment).  Entering into Airplane mode, probably in previous iOS releases as well, immediately disconnects the phone from both cellular and WiFi instantly.  While you can re-enable WiFi, it does automatically disable once Airplane mode is engaged (for me).  If you proactively re-enable WiFi (but leave Airplane mode on), does that change your outcome?

Comment: @gravity ah silly me! I didn't really think of that. That was pretty much it. It did change my outcome. Thanks! You can go ahead and post this as an answer!

Comment: I'm glad it was a simple fix.  Even I was confused, hence my deleted comment once I observed the behavior.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS13, and possibly earlier versions (that I do not have immediately available to test on), once you enable "Airplane mode," the WiFi is automatically disconnected.

An end-user would need to proactively reenable WiFi on their device to reconnect, while still having Airplane mode enabled.

Your `if` statement isn't getting executed, likely because there's no network information yet.  Reenabling WiFi should get you the expected results.